# Row level security in Excel - what approach should I use:

Tags: vba, excel

Morning folks,

Over the last couple of days I have been trying to find a way of implementing "pseudo" row level security in Excel using VBA macros.
What I require is to filter all of my Excel table based on the Windows user credentials. The problem is that I am not sure how to tackle this issue and this is the only idea I have so far:

```
 1.Derive the NT account and store it in namedrange
 2. Use autofilter based on NamedRange for each table in my spreadsheet
 3. Delete / Hide the unnecessary rows ?
```

Example:

[image]

Perhaps, there are other ways which are more suitable for my scenario, however I havent been able to find them.
If you could point me into the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: To be clear, your data table contains a column with windows usernames who should be allowed to see each row that username appears in?

Comment: Correct - http://i.stack.imgur.com/pLdze.png

Comment: It should be somewhat doable, but I am not entirely sure I can come up with the solution. I'll try to look into it unless someone beats me to it. I think the NT account can be looked up via some API/COM call, and the sheet can be locked to prevent the changing of the filter. I am not sure if you can prevent code execution against the sheet, however -- and if you can't, then any user can use VBA to retrieve data they aren't meant to see. So I am not yet sure if this endeavor will be what you need.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoveflow @Kiril. Please note that this is not a code writing service and its good for Original Posters (OP) to post some of their code with there question. Having said that, what you want is fairly simple and I have pasted a working answer for Excel 2010 below. Please paste or included some research in future to avoid necessary down vote for you. Enjoy [SO]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by pasting the following into the **ThisWorkBook** Module in your specific WorkBook VBA project. Just remember to save the WorkBook as a .dotm

As mentioned by J.Chomel bypassing WorkBook passwords is not the hardest thing to do and you could find a macro to do that on the net.

Obviously you will need to password protect your VBA project as well to prevent users from accessing the WorkBook password from there.

```
 Private Sub Workbook_Open()

      Dim CurrentUserName As String
      CurrentUserName = Environ("Username")

      Dim WorkBookPassword As String
      'Replace password with your desired password
      WorkBookPassword = "password"

      Dim DataWS1 As Worksheet
      'Replace Sheet1 with your specific sheet name
      Set DataWS1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

      With DataWS1

           .Unprotect WorkBookPassword

           If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False

           .UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=CurrentUserName

           .Protect Contents:=True, _
                    AllowFiltering:=False, _
                    UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
                    Password:=WorkBookPassword
      End With

 End Sub
```

Comment: This answer did present OP what he asked for, but I'll just note for those who are interested that this won't protect against access through VBA. Using an additional, separate workbook or a .vbs, you can view or copy all the data you like.

Comment: @Vegard depending on how secure the data needs to be a password on a `Sheet` or `WorkBook` is sufficient to prevent the average Joe from accessing data which they shouldn't have.

Comment: Agreed, to some extent. It is sufficient if we assume that no user will actively be trying to access information they aren't supposed to have. If this assumption doesn't hold the data is compromised as soon as the workbook is opened.

Comment: That's why I said for the "average Joe". If there is a will there is a way. Enjoy @Vegard

Comment: Indeed, and I do agree. I only felt the need to clarify in order to explicitly warn anyone who has the same needs as OP of the limitations of this protection scheme.

Answer (score 1):

To implement row level security in Excel, you should **avoid retrieving the data in Excel** in the first place. Because if you use vba to filter, it will easily be bypassed by some users. So it could not be called *security*.